# Ajax with webpages

Tags: sql, ajax, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-webpages

I am currently doing a website in visual studio 2012 using web pages(.cshtml). I am trying to implement Ajax which supposed to query the database to populate values on the page. From the examples I've seen on some websites an .asp file is used with the ajax but it is no longer functional in Visual studio. Are the any other ways I could use ajax to query the database? I'm using a SQL database

Ajax code:

```
    function GetPractise()
    {
        var date = document.getElementById('field3-datepicker').value;
        alert(date);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'GetsSlot.asp?q=' + date,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                des = data;
                $("#field2").val(des);

            },

            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textstatus, error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
    }
```

Non functional Classic ASP code :

```
     <% 

        Response.Expires=-1;

        string sql = "Select Practice_Name from Slot where SlotDate='" &     Request.QueryString("p") & "'";   


        set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection");
        conn.Provider="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
        conn.Open(Server.Mappath("SQLAzure"));
        set rs=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
        rs.Open sql,conn

        do until rs.EOF
          for each x in rs.Fields
           response.write("x.value")
          next
          rs.MoveNext
        loop
    %>
```

Comment: It is interesting you are using Ajax request to a php page.

Comment: Do you want a SQL injection attack?  Because this is how you get a SQL injection attack.

Comment: You can also use AJAX to call webmethods on an ASPX page, a web service, or a WCF service hosted in IIS.

Comment: The above code is for Classic ASP. You can do the same in ASP.NET web pages (cshtml) - see http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/220/posting-data-with-jquery-ajax-in-asp-net-razor-web-pages as an example. The method is similar in concept to classic asp.